# How to paste multiple lines at the same time

Tags: notepad++

I have a number of lines that I want to copy and then paste them "vertically". It is easier with an example to understand

Input:

```
line1
line2islonger
line3
line4
```

Output:

```
line1 line1
line2islonger line2islonger
line3 line3
line4 line4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have your input in a text file line by line you'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)`
- Replace with: `\1 \1`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]